# How can i show my webtrends reports in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, webtrends

I am looking to show webtrends analytics report data in a sharepoint portal, how can this be achieved? I would also like to alter the data (calculations) before the data is uploaded.

Comment: Please provide more information about the source of the WebTrends. Is it Google Analytics? SharePoint internal statistics? Something else?

Comment: The data is from my website that is used to generate webtrends profile data, which i eventually want to display on a sharepoint portal.

Answer (score 1):

Are you already exporting these reports, or having them emailed to you (scheduled), in CSV format? If so, you could just open them in Excel and adjust the calculations, then upload the file to your SharePoint portal.

If you are an On Demand customer (meaning you log in at [ondemand.webtrends.com](https://ondemand.webtrends.com)), you also have access to the REST generator (http://generator.webtrends.com). You would just log in with the same account/user/pass. The REST generator can creates a URL for you to paste into a spreadsheet, which will function as a refreshable query, right from the spreadsheet. The only caveats are that there are some report types which aren't support. Scenario Analysis (funnels) for example.